# What is the probability of finding the second qubit as $0$ in the state $|\psi\rangle=\frac1{\sqrt2}|00\rangle+\frac12|10\rangle-\frac12|11\rangle $?

Tags: quantum-state, measurement, textbook-and-exercises

Assuming two qubits start in the state:
$|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}|00\rangle +  \frac{1}{2}|10\rangle- \frac{1}{2}|11\rangle $

What is the probability of measuring the second qubit as 0? And what is the new state of the system after measuring the first qubit as 1?

I know that for a single qubit state that the probability amplitudes are the coefficient squared. In a two qubit system are the probabilities distributed to the individual states? I.e. from this example does the each zero state in the state: $|00⟩$ have a 50% chance?  And I don't really understand the second question, any suggestion on where to review or study?

Comment: State update rules are usually given in books alongside the Born rule (rule to calculate probabilities of measurement outcomes).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If we have the state $|\psi \rangle = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|00\rangle + \dfrac{1}{2}|10\rangle - \dfrac{1}{2}|11\rangle$ then the probability of the second qubit being in the state $|0\rangle$ is the probability of the state $|\psi \rangle$ having $|0\rangle$ on the second qubit. In this case, it is from the states $|00\rangle$ and $|10\rangle$. So The probability of measuring the second qubit in the state $|0\rangle$ is $\bigg| \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \bigg|^2 + \bigg| \dfrac{1}{2} \bigg|^2 = \dfrac{3}{4} $.

You can also work this out more explicitly as well. That is, we have

$$
|\psi \rangle = \begin{pmatrix} 1/\sqrt{2} \ \ \\ 0 \\ 1/2 \\ -1/2 \end{pmatrix}
$$

We are looking for the probability that the second qubit is in the state $|0\rangle$ so the projective measurement $M$ is

$$ 
M = I \otimes |0\rangle \langle 0 | = \begin{pmatrix}  
     1   &  0   &  0  &   0\\
     0  &   0   &  0   &  0\\
     0   &  0   &  1 &    0\\
     0    & 0   &  0   &  0
 \end{pmatrix}
$$
and so according to [Born's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_rule) we have that the probability to measure the second qubit in the state $|0\rangle$ is

$$
 \langle \psi | M | \psi \rangle =  \begin{bmatrix} 1/\sqrt{2} & 0 & 1/2  &-1/2 \end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}  
     1   &  0   &  0  &   0\\
     0  &   0   &  0   &  0\\
     0   &  0   &  1 &    0\\
     0    & 0   &  0   &  0
 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1/\sqrt{2} \ \ \\ 0 \\ 1/2 \\ -1/2 \end{bmatrix} = \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{4} = \dfrac{3}{4}
$$

Also, the state post measurement is $|\psi_{post} \rangle = \dfrac{M|\psi\rangle}{\sqrt{3/4}}$.

You can extend this to the case where the first qubit is mesured in the state $|1\rangle$ too. In this case, the projective measurement $M = |1\rangle \langle 1| \otimes I$